# Image to PDF quality

Tags: linux, pdf, ubuntu-10.04, jpeg, imagemagick

I am converting multiple jpg images to a single PDF using following command

> convert *.jpg mybook.pdf

but the pdf quality is not good.

Is there a way to retain the original quality of images in the pdf?

Answer (score 1):

You might want to try using software like Adobe Acrobat, **but there is no way to create quality in an image**.  Consider uploading to Google Docs, and then re-download the images as a PDF (if you don’t already have Adobe Acrobat).

Answer (score 0):

Let's suppose your original images are with a definition of 300 dpi. You can use

```
convert -set units PixelsPerInch *.jpg -density 300 -page 2647x3745+0+0 mybook.pdf
```

It's possible to choose the *density*, the *geometry* of the page and so on...